# How to get the Ruby documentation from the command line

Tags: ruby, ri

Is there a way to find out which part of my `ri` command that is not showing Ruby's documentation:

```
 $ ruby --version
 ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]

 $ ri --version
 ri 3.12.2     

 $ ri String
 Nothing known about String
```

When I use pry:

```
 $ pry --version
 Pry version 0.9.12 on Ruby 1.9.3

 $ pry 
 [1] pry(main)> ri String
 # shows String documentation
 [2] pry(main)> ri String.split
 error: 'String.split' not found
 [3] pry(main)> ri String.strip
 String.strip not found, maybe you meant:
 String#strip_heredoc
```

What should I do to make the documentation appear?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using `RVM` to manage your Ruby installations you can do this:

```
rvm docs generate
```

If not, try doing this:

```
gem install rdoc-data
rdoc-data --install
```

then try the `ri` command again.

Comment: no, i'm using ruby from archlinux's package manager

Comment: ok, i will try the second one :3 thanks

Comment: As i remarked in my answer, when using pry it's preferable to use the `pry-doc` gem and then `show-doc`

Answer (score 12):

With pry, it's better to install the `pry-doc` gem, and then use the `show-doc` command:

```
[17] pry(main)> show-doc String#inspect

From: string.c (C Method):
Owner: String
Visibility: public
Signature: inspect()
Number of lines: 6

Returns a printable version of _str_, surrounded by quote marks,
with special characters escaped.

   str = "hello"
   str[3] = "\b"
   str.inspect       #=> "\"hel\\bo\""
[18] pry(main)> show-doc Array#pop

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
Signature: pop(*arg1)
Number of lines: 11

Removes the last element from self and returns it, or
nil if the array is empty.

If a number n is given, returns an array of the last n elements
(or less) just like array.slice!(-n, n) does. See also
Array#push for the opposite effect.

   a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
   a.pop     #=> "d"
   a.pop(2)  #=> ["b", "c"]
   a         #=> ["a"]
[19] pry(main)>
```

Note: you can also use the `?` alias for `show-doc` if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned in a comment that you're using the Ruby package from archlinux's package manager. What you need for `ri` is to install the `ruby-docs` package:

```
$ pacman -S ruby-docs
```

I guess they separate the packages so people who don't want the docs can save on disk usage.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use pry:
>
> ```
> $ pry --version
> Pry version 0.9.12 on Ruby 1.9.3
>
> $ pry 
> [1] pry(main)> ri String
> # shows String documentation
> [2] pry(main)> ri String.split
> error: 'String.split' not found
> [3] pry(main)> ri String.strip
> String.strip not found, maybe you meant:
> String#strip_heredoc
> ```
>
> What should I do to make the documentation appear?

Well, there are no methods `String.split` or `String.strip`. There are, however, methods `String#split` and `String#strip`. Try asking for those, and you'll probably get their documentation.

Comment: ah yes, both . and # are not working when in pry, but both works in normal ri comamnd line