# Any way, in the console, to get info on what a certain method does?

Tags: ruby, command-line, console, rubygems

Let's say I use the gem `csv`.

With the following in the console I get a list of all instance methods:

```
require "csv"
csv = CSV.open(FILE_NAME, "a+")
csv.methods
```

One method I now find in the list is e.g. `first`.

Can I from the command line get info about this method? (Yes I know I could google for the docs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pry](http://pryrepl.org) (an IRB alternative) supports [documentation browsing](https://github.com/pry/pry#documentation-browsing):

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'csv'
#=> true

[2] pry(main)> csv = CSV.new('')
#=> <#CSV io_type:StringIO encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"">

[3] pry(main)> show-doc csv.first

From: enum.c (C Method):
Owner: Enumerable
Visibility: public
Signature: first(*arg1)
Number of lines: 8

Returns the first element, or the first n elements, of the enumerable.
If the enumerable is empty, the first form returns nil, and the
second form returns an empty array.

  %w[foo bar baz].first     #=> "foo"
  %w[foo bar baz].first(2)  #=> ["foo", "bar"]
  %w[foo bar baz].first(10) #=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  [].first                  #=> nil
```

According to the docs, you don't have to generate the documentation beforehand:

> The Pry documentation system does not rely on pre-generated `rdoc` or
>   `ri`, instead it grabs the comments directly above the method on demand.
>   This results in speedier documentation retrieval and allows the Pry
>   system to retrieve documentation for methods that would not be picked
>   up by `rdoc`.

Comment: It is probably because you have to install Pry. It might be worth to note that.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is probably ri

```
$ ri 'CSV#first'

= CSV#first

(from ruby core)
=== Implementation from Enumerable
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  enum.first       ->  obj or nil
  enum.first(n)    ->  an_array


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns the first element, or the first n elements, of the enumerable. If the
enumerable is empty, the first form returns nil, and the second form returns
an empty array.

  %w[foo bar baz].first     #=> "foo"
  %w[foo bar baz].first(2)  #=> ["foo", "bar"]
  %w[foo bar baz].first(10) #=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  [].first                  #=> nil
```

You may need to install the docs first as explained in: [How to get the Ruby documentation from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697209/getting-ruby-documentation-from-command-line)